# angular material's md-select can overflow its container

Tags: angular-material

I created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/ariscol/pen/Mvdzqp?editors=1100) to illustrate the problem. Just select all of the options in the dropdown, and you'll see that the display of the selected items will overflow the container. For reference, here's the html that causes the issue:

```
<div><!-- this container needs some arbitrary max-width to be able to see the overflow -->
    <div layout="row"><!-- making this a layout="column" instead of row will fix it -->
        <div layout="column"><!-- putting max-width:100% here will fix it -->
            <md-input-container>
                <md-select ng-model="test" multiple>
                    <!-- md-options -->
                </md-select>
            </md-input-container>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can't figure out why it would overflow, and so I'm not really clear on why the two fixes work. Can anyone explain why this isn't working as written, or propose a better way to avoid the problem?

Update: I found this is a [known issue](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/6312) on the github site, but there is no good resolution there.
Update 2: I found the max-width solution doesn't help in IE11.